# CNN validation dataset doesn't work while model.fit

Tags: conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train my own images with CNN.

However, I split train/validation/test data, and run model.
These are my code.

```
print("train images : {} / train labels : {}".format(train_image.shape, train_label.shape))
print("val images : {} / val labels : {}".format(val_image.shape, val_label.shape))
print("test images : {} / test labels : {}".format(test_image.shape, test_label.shape))
```

> train images : (504, 255, 255, 3) / train labels : (504,)
> val images : (127, 255, 255, 3) / val labels : (127,)
> test images : (158, 255, 255, 3) / test labels : (158,)

```
import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(255, 255, 3)),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.summary()
```

[image]

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop

model.compile(optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.001),
            loss='binary_crossentropy',
            metrics = ['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(train_image, train_label,
                    epochs=100,
                    validation_data = (val_image, val_label),
                    validation_steps=50,
                    verbose=2)
```

[image]

As you can see, validation set works only at first time.
How can I fix this?

Comment: I believe it's related to the use of `validation_steps=50`.

Comment: I searched what is validation_steps, but still no clue. Can you explain it with more details?

Comment: from the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit): "only relevant if `validation_data` is provided **and** is a `tf.data` dataset.", to use `validation_steps` youn need tf.Data not tuple.

Comment: If i understood the docs correctly, you need to create a `tf.Data.Dataset` object out of your validation set and add the repeat function, then continue, or leave it as tuple, but remove the `validation_steps` parameter, or simply use `validation_split` if there is nothing special about how the validation set is picked.

Comment: I remove **validation_steps** and it works as I wanted. Maybe I try to create **tf.Data.Dataset**. Thanks. And one more thing. Does my ID looks korean??

Comment: You are welcome, I'll create an answer now, and Yes, it does look Korean.

Comment: one more thing, it's `tf.data.Dataset` i miss-spilled it in the previous comment, and fixed it in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is using `validation_steps` while the dataset is not of type `tf.data.Dataset`, as stated in the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit):

> **validation_steps**: Only relevant if validation_data is provided and is a tf.data dataset ...

You can solve this by either

1. Changing your validation data to be of type `tf.data.Dataset` ([docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset)) and add `repeat` to have the validation continue without the data being over.
2. Remove the `validation_steps` attribute, this will have it run the validation at each epoch.